# Does the step function defined via a function $f$, converge (in $L^{1}$) to the function $f$?

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a function on $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $ \int_0^1 |f(x)| d x < \infty$ and
- $ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N} f\left( \frac{i}{N} \right) \rightarrow \int f(x) dx$.

Does this imply the convergence
\begin{align}
   \sum_{i=0}^{N}\int_{\Delta_{i,N}} \left| f(x) - f\left( \frac{i}{N} \right) \right| d x = \int_{0}^{1} \left| f(x) -  \sum_{i=0}^{N} f\left( \frac{i}{N} \right) 1_{x \in \Delta_{i,N}} \right| d x
 \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
where $\Delta_{i,N}= \left\{ x \in [0,1] : | \frac{i}{N}-x | \leq \frac{1}{2N} \right\}$?

Obviously that is true for all continuous function $f$, but is it also true for all $f$ that satisfy the two conditions given above?

If not, is it possible to characterise a larger class of functions for which this is true?

Answer (score 1):

You mention $L^1$ in the title but the tags are about the Riemann integral.

If $f$ is Riemann integrable then the answer is yes; this is easy to see from the definition. (Maybe it's simplest to use the version in terms of upper and lower sums.)

On the other hand, $L^1$ refers to the Lebesgue integral. If you've talking about a Lebesgue integrable function the answer is no. Clearly no, since modifying $f$ on a set of measure zero does not change the integral but does change those Riemann sums. For example, start with any $f$ you like such that $\int_0^1 f=0$ but $\int_0^1|f|>0$, and now modify $f$ so $f(j/N)=0$ for all $j,N$.

Comment: Good remark concerning Lebesgue integral.....
For the Riemann integral: Could you please give more details how to show it? (without the absolute value it is obvious, but due to the absolute value within the integral there is more work to do, no?)

Comment: Say $m_j$ is the inf of $f$ on $I_j=[1/N,(j+1)/N]$ and $M_j$ is the sup. The Darboux characterization of Riemann integrability shows that $1/N\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}(M_j-m_j)\to0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: I agree with your result for Riemann integrable functions.
However: For Lebesgue integrable function, your counterexample does not satisfy the condition on the convergence of the sum to the integral... Do you have another counterexample?

Comment: Have you tried at _all_ to find an example  yourself? Given that you can change $f(j/N)$ to anything you want without changing the integral this is trivial. See edit.